# How to make webshim work from greasemonkey userscript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, webshim

im making a userscript putting shims and polyfills into pages. i
included Webshim too, except it doesnt seem to do anything.

this is how i included it:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.16.0/minified/polyfiller.js";

head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML =
"webshims.setOptions('extendNative', true);webshims.polyfill();";

head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

(insertBefore-ing since the script tags run when they are inserted anyway)

this causes webshim to apparently run, and without any errors. im
trying it out on Firefox 3.x, which im pretty sure means it would have
to shim a lot of things, except it doesnt seem to do anything at all.
seeing in Firebug Net panel, it doesnt even seem to connect to any
other .js files, only a shim-ext.css file. i went to webpages which
clearly had video elements and other html5 things, and it still didnt
do anything. i thought i had to put some special class names on the
elements or something, but neither
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/ or
https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim or any stackoverflow posts or
tutorials i found mention that. i thought the problem was that it
couldnt find the other files, but it obviously could find
shim-ext.css, and i found this way to include it on stackoverflow,
with the only difference being that i run it in greasemonkey.

the userscript runs at 'document-start', and i checked that it runs
before any other script and before the  element even exists. if
i specifically request a feature like 'webshim.polyfill('forms');' it
still doesnt work or connect to anything.
the usercript includes ECMAScript 5 shim&sham, ECMAScript 6 shim&sham
and HTML5shiv in the page before Webshim, and its the latest version
of everything. with and without setting basePath and extendNative, its
still the same.

Comment: Setting innerHTML doesn't run embedded scripts. You need to set `textContent` or `text`.

Comment: but im setting it on a newly created script element before inserting it, not something already in page, so it runs when being inserted with the code in it.  with an alert put into it, it alerts too, plus running it manually results in the same thing